# filename.exe has stopped working in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I copied the code of a "card shuffling" program from a book to my CodeBlocks editor and tried to run it. It opens the DOS box and after a second I get an error saying "filename.exe" has stopped working. 
I've checked the code twice and there're no mistakes. Can you guys help me?
Here's the code just in case:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

struct card{
    const char *face;
    const char *suit;
};

typedef struct card Card;
void filldeck(Card * const wDeck, const char *wFace[],const char *wSuit[]);
void shuffle(Card * const wDeck);
void deal(const Card * const wDeck);

int main(void){
    Card deck[52];
    const char *face[]={"Ace","Deuce","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
    const char *suit[]={"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};
    srand(time(NULL));

    fillDeck(deck,face,suit);
    shuffle(deck);
    deal(deck);
    return 0;
}

void fillDeck(Card * const wDeck, const char *wFace[],const char *wSuit){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
        wDeck[i].face=wFace[i%13];
        wDeck[i].suit=wSuit[i/13];
    }
}

void shuffle(Card * const wDeck){
    int i,j;
    Card temp;
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
        j=rand()%52;
        temp=wDeck[i];
        wDeck[i]=wDeck[j];
        wDeck[j]=temp;
    }
}

void deal(const Card * const wDeck){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
        printf("%5s of %-8s%s",wDeck[i].face,wDeck[i].suit,(i+1)%4 ? " ": "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: _" I've checked the code twice and there no mistakes."_ So check a third time using the debugger and step through line by lne.

Comment: We are not your debuggers.

Comment: That `fillDeck` function looks fishy. Why did you write it that way?

Comment: `void fillDeck(Card * const wDeck, const char *wFace[],const char *wSuit)` → `void fillDeck(Card * const wDeck, const char *wFace[],const char *wSuit[])`, `void filldeck(Card * const wDeck, const char *wFace[],const char *wSuit[]);` → `void fillDeck(Card * const wDeck, const char *wFace[],const char *wSuit[]);`, `j=rand()%52;` → `j=rand()%6;`

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the first 6 cards, then shuffle among all 52 of them, which means you're then printing out some uninitialized cards. [Your shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) should be:

```
int n = 6;
for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    j = rand() % (i + 1);
    temp = wDeck[i];
    wDeck[i] = wDeck[j];
    wDeck[j] = temp;
}
```

You also have a typo in the definition of `fillDeck`, missing a `[]`, should be:

```
void fillDeck(Card * const wDeck, const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[])
```

The compiler didn't treat that as an error because the declaration for `fillDeck` has a different letter case (`filldeck`).

It's not a good idea to only initialize 6 cards like that. You should initialize the entire deck, then randomly pluck out cards that you want to deal from those currently remaining in the deck.